# Removing Null Properties from Json in MVC Web Api 4 Beta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm serializing objects and returning as json from my web service. However, I'm trying to omit null properties from serialized json. Is there a way to do this? I'm using Web Api MVC 4 beta.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to leave out.

Answer (score 15):

The ASP.NET Web API currently ([there are plans](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) to change it for the final release to use Json.Net) uses [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908432.aspx) by default to serialize JSON.

So you can control the serialization process with the standard DataContract/DataMember attributes. To skip null properties you can set the [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) to false.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObjet
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to have more control on how the JSON responses are serialized you can use the [WebAPIContrib](http://nuget.org/packages/WebAPIContrib) package which contains formatters using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) or the built in [JavaScriptSeralizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

In Json.Net you can use [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_NullValueHandling.htm) with NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore. Looks like here is no way to do this for whole class, only explicity for each class field/property.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string SometimesNull { get; set; }
```

FYI. There is [a reasons](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/243) why Json.Net by default serialize properties with null values. Take a look, may be some of this reasons applicable to your cases.