# how to remove fields from a json string in .net MVC Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

In my Get method of my REST service,

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
 {
  CustomerRepository lr = new CustomerRepository ();
  IQueryable<Customer> data = lr.GetCustomer();

  var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  resp.Content = new ObjectContent<IQueryable<Customer>>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());        
  return resp;
 }
```

the following test example would be returned to the view as a json string:

```
{ id: '1', name:'California', type:'Student', parent:''}, //parent row
{ id: '2', name:'Harry', type:'Student', parent: '1' },
{ id: '3', name:'James', type:'Student', parent: '1' },
{ id: '4', name:'Sally', type:'Student', parent: '1'},
```

how do I remove the parent row's parent field to be like so before I send it back to UI:

```
{ id: '1', name:'California', type:'Student'}, //parent row
{ id: '2', name:'Harry', type:'Student', parent: '1' },
{ id: '3', name:'James', type:'Student', parent: '1' },
{ id: '4', name:'Sally', type:'Student', parent: '1'},
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

I found a solution.  In my customer class, I just decorate the field.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
 public string parent { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and another one at the same time, I needed to join two tables before sending them via the API..

What I did was create another class that contained only the fields I needed and made a constructor that accepts the first object.

So in this case I would make a "ParentFormat" class with id,name,type, and the constructor of ParentFormat receives a Parent object... then you make another Get method in the API that returns the ParentFormat. There might be a better solution out there but this worked fine for me so I hope it can help you out ;)

EDIT : Actually I knew something bout anonymous types but it was too for in my head, after a 2second search I found this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Using anonymous types seems like a good way and im definitly going to try it

Comment: I saw another one asking something similar but they used data annotation EmitDefaultValue.  But I wasn't able to decorate my classes with DataContract and my properties with DataMember to use EmitDefaultValue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150312/removing-null-properties-from-json-in-mvc-web-api-4-beta

Comment: Thanks for replying, found something even easier:          [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
 public string parent { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks for sharing... add it as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you do not have a very simple application, it is a better idea to use separate dto-classes/viewmodels (data-transfer-objects). In most cases you do not want to expose all data, e.g. the identity or sensitive data. You also dont want your api to be coupled to the business logic and/or the data model.

You can read more about this here: [Does it Make Sense to have ViewModels in the Webapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365773/does-it-make-sense-to-have-viewmodels-in-the-webapi)

Google also has a lot of blog posts about this topic.